# Badbox overfull \hbox without a specific location

Tags: debugging

I am using TexMaker as my editor and got an warning message of
Badbox. However this warning does not give me the details of the
location where the problem happens. Anyone knows how to deal with
this?[image]

My LaTex files contain a main file which includes other files.
Usually it would give me the exact location of where the warning
was taking place. Line 73 without a file name means nothing.

Here is what's in the log file around that message.

```
(./thesismain.toc [1 ] [2]) \tf@toc=\write4 \openout4 =
`thesismain.toc'. [3] (./thesismain.lof [4 ] [5] [6] [7] [8]
Overfull
\hbox (0.84567pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 73--73
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 off-set from the cen-tre, (c)&(d)
15$\OML/cmm/m/it/12
mm$ \OT1 /cmr/m/n/12 off-set from the cen-tre, and (e)&(f) []
[9])
\tf@lof=\write5 \openout5 = `thesismain.lof'. [10]
(./thesismain.lot)
\tf@lot=\write6 \openout6 = `thesismain.lot'. [11 ]
```

Comment: What is in line 73?

Comment: I have no idea which line 73-73 it means. I have a main file which include several other files. Usually it would give me a exact file name where the warning happens but not his warning. In the main file, line 73 is a comment.

Comment: You have a one line paragraph in line 73 of your source file, the log will show you which file is open at that point as each file open is marked with `(/path to file` and each file close is marked with `)`

Comment: so your error is a long caption in a list of figures. You could ignore it or supply a smaller caption in the optional argument to `\caption` or help latex to linebreak it by adding spacing or force linebreak or ...

Comment: you appear to be using 15$mm$   which is very odd markup, units are normally set in roman, and never in math italic.

Comment: TeXmaker tries to show you only the relevant parts, but it can't always do the right thing. It hides stuff from your view. I don't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the complete log. The message 'Overfull \hbox ... lines 73-73' appears within or right after brackets that have the name of the relevant input file at the beginning, like this:

```
[...]
(./other.tex)
Overfull \hbox (473.21613pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--4
[...]
```

TexMaker only shows the error line, but misses the file context.

Update after you've posted the log:
The error is in line 73 of `thesismain.lof`. This file is generated by latex, so the error has its origin somewhere else. As David Carlisle pointed out, it's from a caption. Your best bet is to search for "\caption{...offset from the centre, (c)...}" or similar in your source file(s). Add a shorter description by changing
`\caption{...offset from centre...}` with
`\caption[Short description]{...offset from center...}`

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is really a comment rather than an answer (as it doesn't say what to do about the box) also you should delete the `)` if you indend to show an example of a problem in line 2 of `other.tex` as you show it `other.tex` has been closed so the example would be in some other file, not shown by your fragment.

Comment: Comments requires reputation, which I don't have. (But it seems I can answer here.) I've pasted the output as-is from pdflatex, including the `)`; I don't know why `output.tex` is closed before the error is printed (probably because the paragraph ends in the master.)

Comment: Additionally, the question was how to find the location of the overfull hbox in the source, for which I provide an answer. It was not about how to fix the overfull hbox.